# How to set Listview alternate row color and selected item background color

Tags: android, listview, colors, selector, listitem

I have one list view. I have assigned alternate row colors like below in adapter's getView() method :

```
if(position % 2 ==1)
{
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(231, 249, 255));
}
else
{
convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(195, 240, 255)); 
}
```

Above code is working fine. Now I want to change the color of the selected list item. For that I have followed the below procedure:

I have created on listSelector xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" /> 

</selector>
```

and I have assigned the above selector to my list as below:

```
myList.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector);
```

But I am not getting selected list item color.

Can anyone please tell me how to set alternate row color and selected list item color to an android list.

Comment: [here is answer][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249981/how-to-change-custom-listview-row-color-change-alternatively/21250701?noredirect=1#21250701
may help you for row color change

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

**artists_list_backgroundcolor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/normal" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>

    <color name="normal">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="itemselected">#EDEDED</color>

</resources>
```

**And use it in getView()**

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.HERE_FOR_ALTERNATE);
    }
```

For reference [Link](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-alternate-list.html)

Hope this will help you.